# Assign a value from Json response array object to environment variable in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I have a JSON body response that has an array object in it.

```
{

     "tokens": [
        {
            "baseValue": "need this value to be extracted"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following test script is not able to extract it and set it in the environment variable

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

    pm.test('get value from Response', function(){
            if ( jsonData.tokens.hasOwnProperty("baseValue") ) {
                var xauth = jsData.tokens.baseValue;
                 postman.setEnvironmentVariable("xauth", xauth);
            }
        });
```

What is wrong? Can someone  help me achieve this

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

pm.test('get value from Response', function(){
        if ( jsonData.tokens[0].hasOwnProperty("baseValue") ) {
            var xauth = jsonData.tokens[0].baseValue;
             postman.setEnvironmentVariable("xauth", xauth);
        }
    });
```

The `tokens` property is an array and has a single object, you would need to add `[0]` in the reference to say that you want to use the `baseValue` property within the first object.

You could write it like this with the newer Postman syntax:

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json();

pm.test('get value from Response', function(){
        if ( jsonData.tokens[0].hasOwnProperty("baseValue")) {
             let xauth = jsonData.tokens[0].baseValue;
             pm.environment.set("xauth", xauth);
        }
    });
```